# Sharepoint powershell [username@servername]#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

When I run sharepoint 2010 powershell as administrator, I have [username@servername]#

I don't know why
Help please

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can customize your Windows Powershell command prompt:

[Customizing Windows Powershell command prompt](http://blog.dabasinskas.net/customizing-windows-powershell-command-prompt/)

Comment: In my case how can I run a script ? for exp :   .'c:\....\...ps1 would work ? because I try it and I have some error message

Comment: can you show me  the error message you are receiving?

Answer (score 1):

You may have a default powershell profile that runs a command at launch. I'd check into that. Check these places and see if any were modified to run a command like `whoami` or something similar.
Description

> $Home[My ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Profile.ps1
>
> $Home[My ]Documents\Profile.ps1
>
> $PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
>
> $PsHome\Profile.ps1
>
> $Home[My
>   ]Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
>
> $PsHome\Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/